# Can't format the output the correct way

Tags: java

I have this code to read each line of a file of this type "603,The Matrix,1999-03-30,63000000,136,7.9,9079"
but I only need to read the first 3 parameters and the 3rd one each is a date needs to be read separately, therefor it needs to put the year in a var and the month in other var and then the day in another var but the output I get is this: "[603 | The Matrix | 03-603,The Matrix,1999-1999-03-30"

```
        int i;
        Scanner leitorFicheiroFilmes = new Scanner(ficheiroFilmes);
        ArrayList<Filmes> filme = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; leitorFicheiroFilmes.hasNextLine(); i++) {
            String line = leitorFicheiroFilmes.nextLine();
            String dados[] = linha.split(",");
            if (dados.length == 7) {
                int idFilme = Integer.parseInt(dados[0]);
                String titulo = dados[1];
                String dadosNew[] = line.split("-");
                String ano = dados[2];
                String mes = dadosNew[0];
                String dia = dadosNew[1];
                filme.add(new Filmes(idFilme, title, year, month, day, parseActoresFile(), parseGenerosFile(idFilme)));

            }
        }
```

this is the class with the constructor:

```
 public class Filmes {
     int idFilme;
     String titulo;
     ArrayList<Actores> actores = new ArrayList<Actores>();
     ArrayList<GenerosCinematograficos> generos = new        ArrayList<GenerosCinematograficos>();
    String year, month, day;

     public Filmes(int idFilme, String titulo, String year, String month,     String day, ArrayList<Actores> actores, ArrayList<GenerosCinematograficos>  generos) {
         this.idFilme = idFilme;
         this.titulo = titulo;
         this.year = year;
         this.month = month;
         this.day = day;
         this.actores = actores;
         this.generos = generos;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return idFilme + " | " + titulo + " | " + dia + "-" + mes + "-" + ano;
     }

 }
```

Comment: I would use a CSV parser. If you have a choice on what to use, I would also recommend Python's `pandas` package or R to deal with this sort of data. Java isn't entirely the best tool for this. However that is, stepping this through a debugger would almost certainly solve your problem trivially.

Answer (score 1):

```
String dadosNew[] = line.split("-");
```

must be

```
String dadosNew[] = dados[2].split("-");
```

`dadosNew` array will be `[1999,03,30]` from which you can  get the date, month and year by accessing the correct indices.

Comment: thank you, it's working now has it should, Im new to Java so I didn't knew you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading incorrect values to your variables when parsing the date

```
String dadosNew[] = line.split("-");
String ano = dados[2];
String mes = dadosNew[0];
String dia = dadosNew[1];
```

to

```
String dadosNew[] = dados[2].split("-");
String ano = dadosNew[0];
String mes = dadosNew[1];
String dia = dadosNew[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
String dadosNew[] = line.split("-");
```

With the input (`line`) being `"603,The Matrix,1999-03-30,63000000,136,7.9,9079"` The result wille be :

```
{"603,The Matrix,1999", "03", "30,63000000,136,7.9,9079"}
```

---

You want to split only the date, and this is contained in `dados[2]`, so to correct it you have to do :

```
String dadosNew[] = dados[2].split("-");
```